# jquery tooltip with dynamic div

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I have in my partial view a link. I want the "tooltip" to be shown if user hovers on that link. 
So far I've tried several tooltip jquery plugins but they almost all use title element. I want a div to be shown when user hovers on the link. Additionally, all those plugins use element classes and not ids. I want to use Id because on the page I will have about 10 partial views with different content. Obviously when user hovers on a specific link generated in a specific partial view, the appropriate div should be shown. 
Can someone please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the jQuery [qTip2 plugin](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/).

Answer (score 0):

qTip2 - http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/ - this plugin is the best one and can be customized in many different ways (including your idea).

btw. I would not use the same id for more then one element as this is not recommended. I would use something like data-id="commonName" or add another class like this class="existingClass anotherClass yourClassTooltip" as its a standard.